# Serialize Property that contains XDocument

Tags: c#, linq, xaml

I have a class that I am serializing using `System.Xaml.XamlObjectReader` and the `System.Xaml.XamlXmlWriter`. Everything goes good on everything until I get to my property that contains an `XDocument`. I get Unable to serialize type 'System.Xml.Linq.XDeclaration'.

How can I during my while loop to serialize the object nodes to disk get it to write out the xml in this property?

Comment: Do you need the entire document? Try serializing just the root XElement.

Comment: Yes, it is a template for a web.config that we ship with our product and I need to save it with the rest of the settings so they can use the whole file with our program to apply all those settings.

Comment: Yes, but do you need the `<?xml` part?

Comment: No I just need the <configuration> tags and all the children under it.

Comment: I just tried to serialize the root and it fails because XElement has no default constructor. Which is the same reason XDocument fails because it contains properties that do not have a default constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert this to CData and serialize it.
You can refer this example for details
[How do you serialize a string as CDATA using XmlSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379888/how-do-you-serialize-a-string-as-cdata-using-xmlserializer)

Or you can also escape xml tags of ToString() of XDocument. e.g. [String escape into XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132494/string-escape-into-xml)

Comment: I'm not at a computer right now, but this will work with the xamlwriter?

Comment: I basically took what you said only I converted to a string first. All the XML escaping is ugly, but it works thanks.

Comment: You should also be able to serialize the root using XML Serialization, since XElement implements IXmlSerializable. XDocument does not.