# Removing Invalid Characters From XML File Before Deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have some XML I am receiving from a server that sometimes has some invalid characters that I would like to remove before deserialization. I have no control over the XML file I receive so I need to check for the invalid characters myself.

Sample XML.....

```
<PrintStatus>N</PrintStatus>
<CustomerPO> >>>> pearl <<<<< </CustomerPO>
<Description>PO# pearl</Description>
<BranchID>4</BranchID>
<PostDate>
   <Date>01/13/2015</Date>
</PostDate>
<ShipDate>
   <Date>01/13/2015</Date>
</ShipDate>
```

As you can see, the customer po section has the invalid characters I need to remove.  This sometimes occurs only in certain elements that include user typed data.

Here is my Response code.....

```
//configure http request
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
httpRequest.Method = "POST";

//prepare correct encoding for XML serialization
UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();

//use Xml property to obtain serialized XML data
//convert into bytes using encoding specified above and get length
byte[] bodyBytes = encoding.GetBytes(Xml);
httpRequest.ContentLength = bodyBytes.Length;

//get http request stream for putting XML data into
Stream httpRequestBodyStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();

//fill stream with serialized XML data
httpRequestBodyStream.Write(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length);
httpRequestBodyStream.Close();

//get http response
HttpWebResponse httpResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
StreamReader httpResponseStream = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);

//extract XML from response
string httpResponseBody = httpResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
httpResponseStream.Close();

//ignore everything that isn't XML by removing headers
httpResponseBody = httpResponseBody.Substring(httpResponseBody.IndexOf("<?xml"));

//deserialize XML into ProductInquiryResponse
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyResponseClass));
StringReader responseReader = new StringReader(httpResponseBody);

//return MyResponseClass result
return serializer.Deserialize(responseReader) as MyResponseClass;
```

Does anyone happen to have any suggestions to check the XML?  Should I just check the elements I am concerned with right before the xml string gets deserialized? Or is there a better way?

Comment: If it has invalid characters, then it is not XML. Maybe the service owners don't know they are sending garbage. You should tell them so they have a chance of fixing their bug.

Comment: that content should be in [CData](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) section..can you change it on the server or request for it? I dont think you should be removing that!

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I agree John. I tried getting it fixed many times at the source but no luck. I have no choice but to check and remove the characters myself.

Answer (score 0):

A general fix for your problem would be to recursively descend the XML, parsing as you go and comparing to the schema for that node.  At any point if the input differs from the input expected from the schema, or is malformed in some way, allow an error handler to run to fix the input stream, rolling back to the most recent good state and proceeding forward with the fixed input.

The .Net `XmlTextReader` class is not flexible enough to do this.  However, if you know in advance that from the schema that certain XML Elements *cannot have children*, then the following will read an XML input stream, and upon encountering an element whose fully qualified name matches the known names of leaf nodes, and "escape" the text of all such nodes:

```
public enum XmlDoctorStatus
{
    NoFixNeeded,
    FixMade,
    FixFailed
}

public class XmlDoctor
{
    internal class XmlFixData
    {
        public string InitialXml { get; private set; }
        public string FixedXml { get; private set; }
        public int LineNumber { get; private set; }
        public int LinePosition { get; private set; }

        public XmlFixData(string initialXml, string fixedXml, int lineNumber, int linePosition)
        {
            this.InitialXml = initialXml;
            this.FixedXml = fixedXml;
            this.LineNumber = lineNumber;
            this.LinePosition = linePosition;
        }

        public bool ComesAfter(XmlFixData other)
        {
            if (LineNumber > other.LineNumber)
                return true;
            if (LineNumber == other.LineNumber && LinePosition > other.LinePosition)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    }

    internal class XmlFixedException : Exception
    {
        public XmlFixData XmlFixData { get; private set; }

        public XmlFixedException(XmlFixData data)
        {
            this.XmlFixData = data;
        }
    }

    readonly HashSet<XName> childlessNodes;

    public string OriginalXml { get; private set; }

    public XmlDoctor(string xml, IEnumerable<XName> childlessNodes)
    {
        if (xml == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.OriginalXml = xml;
        this.childlessNodes = new HashSet<XName>(childlessNodes);
    }

    List<int> indices = null;
    string passXml = string.Empty;
    bool inPass = false;

    void InitializePass(string xml)
    {
        if (inPass)
            throw new Exception("nested pass");
        ClearElementData();
        TextHelper.NormalizeLines(xml, out passXml, out indices);
        inPass = true;
    }

    void EndPass()
    {
        inPass = false;
        indices = null;
        passXml = string.Empty;
        ClearElementData();
    }

    static int LineNumber(XmlReader reader)
    {
        return ((IXmlLineInfo)reader).LineNumber;
    }

    static int LinePosition(XmlReader reader)
    {
        return ((IXmlLineInfo)reader).LinePosition;
    }

    // Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132494/string-escape-into-xml

    public static string XmlEscape(string escaped)
    {
        var replacements = new KeyValuePair<string, string>[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("&", "&amp;"),
            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("\"", "&quot;"),
            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("'", "&apos;"),
            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("<", "&lt;"),
            new KeyValuePair<string,string>(">", "&gt;"),
        };

        foreach (var pair in replacements)
            foreach (var index in escaped.IndexesOf(pair.Key, 0).Reverse())
                if (!replacements.Any(other => string.Compare(other.Value, 0, escaped, index, other.Value.Length, StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0))
                {
                    escaped = escaped.Substring(0, index) + pair.Value + escaped.Substring(index + 1, escaped.Length - index - 1);
                }
        return escaped;
    }

    void HandleNode(XmlReader reader)
    {
        // Adapted from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mfussell/archive/2005/02/12/371546.aspx
        if (reader == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("reader");
        }

        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                HandleStartElement(reader);
                if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
                {
                    HandleEndElement(reader);
                }
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                HandleText(reader);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Whitespace:
            case XmlNodeType.SignificantWhitespace:
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
            case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.DocumentType:
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                HandleEndElement(reader);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void HandleText(XmlReader reader)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentElementLocalName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentElementName))
            return;
        var name = XName.Get(currentElementLocalName, currentElementNameSpace);
        if (!childlessNodes.Contains(name))
            return;
        var lineIndex = LineNumber(reader) - 1;
        var charIndex = LinePosition(reader) - 1;
        if (lineIndex < 0 || charIndex < 0)
            return;

        int startIndex = indices[lineIndex] + charIndex;

        // Scan forward in the input string until we find either the beginning of a CDATA section or the end of this element.
        // Patterns to match:  </Name
        // 
        string pattern1 = "</" + currentElementName;
        var index1 = FindElementEnd(passXml, startIndex, pattern1);
        if (index1 < 0)
            return;  // BAD XML.
        string pattern2 = "<![CDATA[";
        var index2 = passXml.IndexOf(pattern2, startIndex);
        int endIndex = (index2 < 0 ? index1 : Math.Min(index1, index2));
        var text = passXml.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);

        var escapeText = XmlEscape(text);
        if (escapeText != text)
        {
            if (escapeText != XmlEscape(escapeText))
            {
                Debug.Assert(escapeText == XmlEscape(escapeText));
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Escaping error");
            }
            string fixedXml = passXml.Substring(0, startIndex) + escapeText + passXml.Substring(endIndex, passXml.Length - endIndex);
            throw new XmlFixedException(new XmlFixData(passXml, fixedXml, lineIndex + 1, charIndex + 1));
        }
    }

    static bool IsXmlSpace(char ch)
    {
        // http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#NT-S
        // [3]      S      ::=      (#x20 | #x9 | #xD | #xA)+
        return ch == '\u0020' || ch == '\u0009' || ch == '\u000D' || ch == '\u000A';
    }

    private static int FindElementEnd(string passXml, int charPos, string tagEnd)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var index = passXml.IndexOf(tagEnd, charPos);
            if (index < 0)
                return index;
            int endPos = index + tagEnd.Length;
            if (index + tagEnd.Length >= passXml.Length)
                return -1; // Bad xml?
            // Now we must have zero or more white space characters and a ">"
            while (endPos < passXml.Length && IsXmlSpace(passXml[endPos]))
                endPos++;
            if (endPos >= passXml.Length)
                return -1; // BAD XML;
            if (passXml[endPos] == '>')
                return index;
            index = endPos;
            // Spurious ending, keep searching.
        }
    }

    string currentElementName = string.Empty;
    string currentElementNameSpace = string.Empty;
    string currentElementLocalName = string.Empty;

    private void HandleStartElement(XmlReader reader)
    {
        currentElementName = reader.Name;
        currentElementLocalName = reader.LocalName;
        currentElementNameSpace = reader.NamespaceURI;
    }

    private void HandleEndElement(XmlReader reader)
    {
        ClearElementData();
    }

    private void ClearElementData()
    {
        currentElementName = string.Empty;
        currentElementNameSpace = string.Empty;
        currentElementLocalName = string.Empty;
    }

    public XmlDoctorStatus TryFix(out string newXml)
    {
        XmlFixData data = null;

        while (true)
        {
            XmlFixData newData;
            var status = TryFixOnePass((data == null ? OriginalXml : data.FixedXml), out newData);
            switch (status)
            {
                case XmlDoctorStatus.FixFailed:
                    Debug.WriteLine("Could not fix XML");
                    newXml = OriginalXml;
                    return XmlDoctorStatus.FixFailed;

                case XmlDoctorStatus.FixMade:
                    if (data != null && !newData.ComesAfter(data))
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Warning -- possible infinite loop detected, aborting fix");
                        newXml = OriginalXml;
                        return XmlDoctorStatus.FixFailed;
                    }
                    data = newData;
                    break;  // Try to fix more

                case XmlDoctorStatus.NoFixNeeded:
                    if (data == null)
                    {
                        newXml = OriginalXml;
                        return XmlDoctorStatus.NoFixNeeded;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newXml = data.FixedXml;
                        return XmlDoctorStatus.FixMade;
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    XmlDoctorStatus TryFixOnePass(string xml, out XmlFixData data)
    {
        try
        {
            InitializePass(xml);

            using (var textReader = new StringReader(passXml))
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(textReader))
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    bool read = reader.Read();
                    if (!read)
                        break;
                    HandleNode(reader);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (XmlFixedException ex)
        {
            // Success - a fix was made.
            data = ex.XmlFixData;
            return XmlDoctorStatus.FixMade;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Failure - the file was not fixed and could not be parsed.
            Debug.WriteLine("Fix Failed: " + ex.ToString());
            data = null;
            return XmlDoctorStatus.FixFailed;
        }
        finally
        {
            EndPass();
        }
        // No fix needed.
        data = null;
        return XmlDoctorStatus.NoFixNeeded;
    }
}

public static class TextHelper
{
    public static void NormalizeLines(string text, out string newText, out List<int> lineIndices)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var indices = new List<int>();

        using (var sr = new StringReader(text))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                indices.Add(sb.Length);
                sb.AppendLine(line);
            }
        }

        lineIndices = indices;
        newText = sb.ToString();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> IndexesOf(this string str, string value, int startAt)
    {
        if (str == null)
            yield break;
        for (int index = startAt, valueLength = value.Length; ; index += valueLength)
        {
            index = str.IndexOf(value, index);
            if (index == -1)
                break;
            yield return index;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
public static class TestXmlDoctor
{
    public static void TestFix()
    {
        string xml1 = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<MainClass>
<PrintStatus>N</PrintStatus>
<CustomerPO> >>>> pearl <<<<< </CustomerPO>
<Description>PO# pearl</Description>
<BranchID>4</BranchID>
<PostDate>
   <Date>01/13/2015</Date>
</PostDate>
<ShipDate>
   <Date>01/13/2015</Date>
</ShipDate>
</MainClass>
";
        XName[] childlessNodes1 = new XName[] 
        {
            XName.Get("CustomerPO", string.Empty),
        };
        try
        {
            TestFix(xml1, childlessNodes1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    public static string TestFix(string xml, IEnumerable<XName> childlessNodes)
    {
        string fixedXml;
        var status = (new XmlDoctor(xml, childlessNodes).TryFix(out fixedXml));
        switch (status)
        {
            case XmlDoctorStatus.NoFixNeeded:
                return xml;
            case XmlDoctorStatus.FixFailed:
                Debug.WriteLine("Failed to fix xml");
                return xml;
            case XmlDoctorStatus.FixMade:
                Debug.WriteLine("Fixed XML, new XML is as follows:");
                Debug.WriteLine(fixedXml);
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Empty);
                return fixedXml;
            default:
                Debug.Assert(false, "Unknown fix status " + status.ToString());
                return xml;
        }
    }
}
```

This with this, your XML fragment can be parsed, and becomes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MainClass>
<PrintStatus>N</PrintStatus>
<CustomerPO> &gt;&gt;&gt;&gt; pearl &lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt; </CustomerPO>
<Description>PO# pearl</Description>
<BranchID>4</BranchID>
<PostDate>
   <Date>01/13/2015</Date>
</PostDate>
<ShipDate>
   <Date>01/13/2015</Date>
</ShipDate>
</MainClass>
```