# hexadecimal value 0x0B, is an invalid character issue in XML

Tags: asp.net, xml

[image]

I am getting exception

> '', hexadecimal value 0x0B, is an invalid character. Line 23, position 22.

I have already tried solution from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762/how-do-you-remove-invalid-hexadecimal-characters-from-an-xml-based-data-source-p), but it is not working for me. As my project is in **3.5** version, I cannot use `XmlConvert.IsXmlChar` method [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.isxmlchar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

How to  handle it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XMLTextReader is created but XslCompiledTransform.Transform fails with invalid character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282249/xmltextreader-is-created-but-xslcompiledtransform-transform-fails-with-invalid-c)

Comment: Are you able to edit your [XML Character Range](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets)?

Answer (score 8):

You can replace these invalid characters using the below method.

```
public static string CleanInvalidXmlChars(this string StrInput)
    {
        //Returns same value if the value is empty.
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StrInput))
        {
            return StrInput;
        }
        // From xml spec valid chars:
        // #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]    
        // any Unicode character, excluding the surrogate blocks, FFFE, and FFFF.
        string RegularExp = @"[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\xD7FF\xE000-\xFFFD\x10000-x10FFFF]";
        return Regex.Replace(StrInput, RegularExp, String.Empty);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to remove the vertical tab (hexadecimal value 0x0B) from the string (e.g. database export), you can also set `CheckCharacters` to `false` in your `XmlWriterSettings`.

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the XML writer should
> check to ensure that all characters in the document conform to the
> "2.2 Characters" section of the W3C XML 1.0 Recommendation. Returns:
> true to do character checking; otherwise, false. The default is true.

e.g.

```
private static System.Xml.XmlWriter CreateXmlWriter(System.IO.Stream stream)
{
    System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings xs = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
    xs.Indent = true;
    xs.IndentChars = "    ";
    xs.NewLineChars = System.Environment.NewLine;
    xs.OmitXmlDeclaration = false; // // <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    // xs.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; // doesn't work with pgsql 
    // xs.Encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false);
    xs.Encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false, false);
    xs.Async = true;
    xs.CheckCharacters = false;
    
    return System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(stream, xs);
} // End Function CreateXmlWriter
```