# Escape XML on Windows Mobile 6

Tags: xml, encoding, windows-mobile

I know there's this:

```
var encoded = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(unencoded)
```

But System.Security namespace seems to be unavailable on Windows Mobile 6. Is there an equivalent approach that works on mobile devices?

Comment: I see now that this could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132494/string-escape-into-xml.

Comment: It's not a strict duplicate because in the other question there's not mention about the use of this pattern on mobile devices, but the accepted response of the other question works for this issue. I'll add a comment on mobile devices in the correct answer, so this could be marked as duplicate.