# Why does LINQ to XML not escape characters like '\x1A'?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I get exception if in `XElement`'s content I include characters such as '\x1A', '\x1B', '\x1C', '\x1D', '\x1E' or '\x1F'.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace LINQtoXMLInvalidChars
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly IReadOnlyCollection<char> InvalidCharactersInXml = new List<char>
        {
            '<',
            '>',
            '&',
            '\'',
            '\"',
            '\x1A',
            '\x1B',
            '\x1C',
            '\x1D',
            '\x1E',
            '\x1F'
        };

        static void Main()
        {
            foreach (var c in InvalidCharactersInXml)
            {
                var xEl = new XElement("tag", "Character: " + c);
                var xDoc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null), xEl);

                try
                {
                    Console.Write("Writing " + c + ": ");
                    Console.WriteLine(xDoc);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Oops.    " + e.Message);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

[In an answer from Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1132516/1986541) to the question [String escape into XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132494/1986541) I read

> You set the text in a node, and it will automatically escape anything it needs to.

So now I'm confused. Do I misunderstand something?

**Some background information:** The string content of the `XElement` comes from the end user. I see two options for making my application robust: **1)** to Base-64 encode the string before passing it in to `XElement` **2)** to narrow the accepted set of characters to e.g. alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of those characters simply aren't valid in XML 1.0 at all. Personally I wish that LINQ to XML would fail to produce a document that later it wouldn't be able to parse, but basically you should avoid them.

I would also recommend avoiding `\x` as an escape sequence anyway, preferring `\u` - the fact that `\x` will take "up to" 4 hex digits can be very confusing.

From the [XML 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets):

> `Char ::=  #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]`

Now U+000D and U+000A are interesting cases - they won't be escaped in text nodes; they'll just be included verbatim. Whether or not that's then present when you *parse* the node will depend on parse settings (and whether there are non-whitespace characters around it).

In terms of how to handle this in your case: you definitely have options of:

- Performing your own encoding/escaping. This is generally somewhat painful, and will lead to XML documents which are hard to read compared with regular ones. You could *potentially* do this only when required, adding an attribute to the element to say that you've done it, for example.
- Detect and remove characters which are invalid in XML
- Detect and *reject* strings containing characters which are invalid in XML

We can't really tell which of these is most appropriate in your scenario.

Comment: Jon, many thanks! I added some background information as a comment to the original question. I would be interested in your opinion on how application developers usually approach this situation.

Comment: @GyulaKósa: The background information should be in the question itself, not a comment. I'll amend my answer appropriately.

Comment: I would like my serialization technology chosen (XML in this case) to be _transparent_ to the user of my component, so I would like to avoid _rejecting_ inputs just because they contain characters that are invalid in XML. _Removing_ characters is not an option to me unfortunately. There remains performing my _own encoding/escaping_ that really seems to be painful. Currently I am using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10380166/1986541) approach to Base64-encode the byte representation of my string, but I have reservations because of the potential problem of endianness, for example.

Comment: @GyulaKósa: That's a terrible approach to encoding characters as bytes. You should at least use UTF-8 or something similar. Is the use of XML entirely enforced on you? Because if you're not using it as a textual representation really, it's a terribly inefficient approach...

Comment: Unfortunately the use of XML is enforced on me, but it does not really matter if the string is written out as is or encoded. [XmlConvert.EncodeName(String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.encodename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is almost what I need, but it was meant for the _name_ of the element, not for the _content_. I get the impression that XML limits its use, and it is not really meant for storing plain vanilla `string` .NET objects.

Comment: I did consider using [UTF-8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but it has also limitation e.g. being unable to encode `\uD802`.

Comment: @GyulaKósa: No, it can encode U+D802 just fine - as part of a surrogate pair. If you have a string including U+D802 without a corresponding low surrogate, that's simply not a well-formed Unicode string. You really need to think about what you're trying to support. There's a big difference between serializing "any well-formed Unicode string" and "any sequence of UTF-16 code units".

Comment: I think I wrongly assumed that ["a series of Unicode characters"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) i.e. a `String` object is always a well-formed Unicode string.

Comment: Let's assume that the string is a well-formed Unicode string. Do you think that it's a good approach to encode it using `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` and then `System.Convert.ToBase64String` **if** `System.Xml.XmlConvert.VerifyXmlChars` throws `XmlException`? Thanks.

Comment: @Gyula: That MSDN documentation is unfortunate. A string is actually a sequence of UTF-16 code units. But yes, that approach should be okay - add an attribute to the element to indicate that it's base64.

Comment: Readers of this conversation may find reading [When is a string not a string?](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/11/07/when-is-a-string-not-a-string/comment-page-1/) blog post useful.