# Escapes &quot; on xml tag

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file , where there is a tag with the following "Test" value. I need to open the xml file using a text editor to tag appears as follows

```
<infd>&quot;Test&quot;</infd>
```

Someone would know to do this using C # ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String escape into XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132494/string-escape-into-xml)

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you asking how to start a text editor?

Comment: No, I meant that I'm creating an XML file and when I open it using a text editor tag which used the exhaust is displayed with the following value <infd>&amp; quot; Test &amp; quot; </ infd>. I would like to know that it was displayed as it is displayed in the open XML file via browser.